# global asax file

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the global asax file for? I'm looking to declare a user-specific dictionary of objects that'll be used throughout the pages of the application. Where do I declare this dictionary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Global.asax file is for defining application-level event handling. There are various events like application launch, session start... here is a link to MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwzzh56s.aspx.

For your scenario use the session start event for persisting information for a session.

Comment: Ok, I get the concept of the global asax. I created a file called AppObjects. It has 2 namespaces that store user objects and reporting objects. I'd like to add a third namespace called SessionObjects and in this namespace, declare a dictionary that stores lists and uses a date as the key. Where and how would I do this definition?

Comment: what problem are you facing.. if u get the list and the list might in some class so you can straight away add it to Session["MyList"]=you class containing list. To use it just cast it back to the class and retrive the items from list... this is just a sterategy  ... use it as er your requirements....

Answer (score 5):

Global.asax contains a class representing your application as a whole. If your dictionary is user-specific (i.e. not common to all users), you need to store it in a user-specific location. The first thing which comes to mind when you need to keep something user-specific is to use the session storage. (See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).)

**Added** per comment:

```
public static class SessionObjects
{
    public static Dictionary<DateTime, List<int>> MySessionStoredLists
    {
            get
            {
                    var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
                    if (session == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
                    var fromSession = (Dictionary<DateTime, List<int>>)session["MySessionStoredLists"];
                    if (fromSession == null)
                    {
                            fromSession = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<int>>();
                            MySessionStoredLists = fromSession;
                    }
                    return fromSession;
            }
            private set
            {
                session["MySessionStoredLists"] = value;
            }
    }
}
```

This is just an example, but your idea seems a bit suspicious to me – do you want to keep something per-user per-date basis? Isn’t a full-featured persistent storage in a database better?

Comment: I created a file called AppObjects. It has 2 namespaces that store user objects and reporting objects. I'd like to add a third namespace called SessionObjects and in this namespace, declare a dictionary that stores lists and uses a date as the key. Where and how would I do this definition?

Answer (score 3):

`Global.asax` file is used to register some application global events like: application starts, request begins, an unhandled exception propagates, ... User-specific stuff should be stored into the [`Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

Comment: I created a file called AppObjects. It has 2 namespaces that store user objects and reporting objects. I'd like to add a third namespace called SessionObjects and in this namespace, declare a dictionary that stores lists and uses a date as the key. Where and how would I do this definition?

Answer (score 1):

The global.asax file is an application class where you can handle various application level events. [Link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2027ewzw.aspx).

If you are happy to store this dictionary in the Session (which is specific to each user), you could initialise it in the [Session_Start event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee255113%28v=BTS.10%29.aspx)